# Prove there exist a unique $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ n \leq \sqrt{10} \leq n+1$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

this is my first year in college and my first lesson in algebra is logic and i have this question as an application of the Existential quantification that demand to  Show that :

$\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \leq \sqrt{10} \leq  n+1 $

we know that $\sqrt{10} >\sqrt{9}=3 $

and $3\in \mathbb{N}$ , so 3 verifies the inéquation

My problem is how should i write the demonstration properly and show the unicity .

Comment: There is a typo: $\sqrt{19}$ should probably be $\sqrt{9}$.

Comment: yes , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$9<10<16 \Rightarrow 3=\sqrt9<\sqrt{10}<\sqrt{16}=4$. So $n=3$ works.

FOr the univity. Assume thare are two of them, say $n$ and $m$. That is $n\le \sqrt{10}\le n+1$ and $m\le\sqrt{10}\le m+1$.

$n\le \sqrt{10}\le n+1$ and $-m-1\le-\sqrt{10}\le -m$. By substracting them, you'll get

$$n-m-1\le 0\le n-m +1 \iff m-1\le n\le m+1$$.

If $n=m-1$ would imply that $\sqrt{10}\in[n,n+1]\cap[n+1,n+2]={n+1}$, so $\sqrt{10}\in\Bbb N$, wich is impossible.

The same occur in the case $n=m+1\iff m=n-1$.

So the only possibility is $n=m$ and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach.  Assume that there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $m \neq 3$ and $m \leq \sqrt{10} \leq (m+1).$

$\underline{\text{case 1:}}$ 
$m < 3 \implies \sqrt{10} \leq (m+1) \leq 3 \implies 10 \leq (3^2) = 9 ~ \otimes.$

$\underline{\text{case 2:}}$ 
$m > 3 \implies \sqrt{10} \geq m \geq 4 \implies 10 \geq (4^2) = 16 ~ \otimes.$